# Why does my RelativeLayout background become black when I add a button to it?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-relativelayout

I have some code below that creates a RelativeLayout and adds a button to it.  It draws fine when created from onCreate(), shows a blue button on a red background.

But when creating a new ReltativeLayout when clicking on the first the new button shows on a black background, so my RelativeLayout doesn't show.

The funny thing is that it works if I comment out the line that adds the button, so somehow the button is impacting the relative layout.

Thanks for any help.

```
package com.android.mikeviewtester;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ViewTesterActivity extends Activity {

    void createNewView( int bgColor, int btnColor ) {

        // create a new relative layout
        android.widget.RelativeLayout newView = new android.widget.RelativeLayout( this );

        // create a button
        Button btn = new Button( this );

        // set the background color
        btn.setBackgroundColor( btnColor );

        // create a layoutParams struct for adding the button to the relative layout view
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( 100, 100 );

        // add the button to the relative layout
        newView.addView( btn, params );

        // set the relative layout background color
        newView.setBackgroundColor( bgColor );

        // set the ontouch listener for the relativeLayout
        newView.setOnTouchListener( (android.view.View.OnTouchListener) mOnTouchListener );

        // create the layout to fill the activity
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        // set the relative layout as the view
        setContentView( newView, viewParams );
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        // create and set the initial view
        createNewView( Color.RED, Color.BLUE );
    }

    // ios - (void)buttonWasPressed:(id)whichButton {
    private android.view.View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener = new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if ( v != null )
                v.onTouchEvent( event );

            if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {

                // create and set a new view
                createNewView( Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA );
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Try setting the viewParams to your RelativeLayout instead of setting it in setContentView()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a change in your code, i.e. add `v.setVisibility(View.GONE);` before calling `createNewView(Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA);`

Comment: Sorry to do this, but now in real world code I see it doesn't work because I'm not using a hard-coded size (500x500) but instead I'm using FILL_PARENT.  Your fix worked for 500x500 but not for FILL_PARENT.  I edited the code above.  Could you maybe explain why your suggested solved the problem could help me answer my own question.  Thanks.

Comment: clearly ask your question? i have suggested the solution because because you are not removing the view before adding other view.

Comment: Maybe it's simplest if I just start over and re-ask the original question with the updated code.  Why does the code above result in a magenta button on a screen of black after clicking?  Why doesnt the green show up layout show up?